# How to connect PHP with MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, database, nosql

I am planning to develop a website using noSQL.But i am unaware of connecting PHP with other databases other than mySQL.I know basics of MongoDB which is a document based database.
How can i connect PHP to MongoDB database? Is there any tutorial regarding it?

Comment: bro i have tried mongoDB with node.js but i want a PHP connectivity with mongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [MongoClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php). You can install this extension from [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo) repository.

Answer (score -1):

1. check your php version file at C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64 / php8ts.dll
2. download dll file from https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.13.0/windows based on php8ts.dll file
3. download 8.1 Thread Safe (TS) x64
4. you will get a php_mongodb-1.13.0-8.1-ts-vs16-x64.zip
5. copy php_mongodb.dll file in ext folder of php
6. C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64\ext
7. edit C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64 / php.ini file and add
8. extension=mongodb
9. restart server
10. install composer in windows
11. open command prompt
12. goto your project directory www/<your_project>
13. create composer.json file

> {
> "require": {
> "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.12"
> }
> }

14. run command > composer require mongodb/mongodb

    selectCollection('iitj', 'home');
    $document = $collection->findOne();

    var_dump($document);