# How to connect to MongoDB with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have been searching a lot online and I can't find anything on it. I found one video on youtube, I added this line to my php.ini

```
extension = php_mongo.dll
```

and I also tried

```
extension = mongodb
```

However, when I go into powershell and check, the extension isn't shown:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

However, I do receive this error, regarding my php_mongodb.dll file:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mongodb.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_mongodb.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
```

This is where I added the line in my code:

[image]

I also found this answer on stack overflow but it is outdated: [How to connect PHP with MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688326/how-to-connect-php-with-mongodb)

I need to connect to MongoDB with php, if someone could help me thatd be amazing.

thanks

Comment: Do a `>php --ini` and look at the output for `Loaded Configuration File:` Is that the `php.ini` file that you made the changes in?

Comment: Secondly, I have to ask.... Did you install MondoDB, as the php extension is not the actualy MongoDB itself?

Comment: Yes I have created a cluster and have been looking around in compass, MongoDB is all installed

Comment: and this was the output :

'PS C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Extract\ext> php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
PS C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Extract\ext>'

Comment: So was `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` the file you added the `extension = mongodb` to?

Comment: Does it work if you use the command window instead of PowerShell

Comment: An extension name can't just be made up. Does a file exist in your extensions directory with the name `php_mongo.dll` or `mongodb.dll`? I suspect not, which is why they aren't showing as loaded. You'll need to use the correct extension name for it to load properly. (Also file extensions like `dll` or `so` are not used in load statements any longer.)

Comment: If you do a search `install mongo to xampp` you will get a whole bunch of tutorials

Comment: Embarrassingly I was checking in the wrong location in powershell, but now checking in the correct location (xampp), it still does not show, and yes I have a  'php_mongodb.dll' file, however now adding it to the xampp file I receive an error I will update the question with

Comment: @RiggsFolly Looks like a lot of info think I will find my answer in there thank you!

Comment: Bear in mind, in PHP you have the mongo **library** and the mongo **extension**. The [extension](https://www.php.net/mongodb) provides a low-level API to Mongo, the [library](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/) provides high-level commands similar to normal shell commands